# Facebook FB.ui oauth dialog error

Tags: facebook, fb.ui

I'm having problems making a dialog box to ask for a user to log into my facebook tab to enter a contest.

We're trying to use the FB.ui oauth dialog box with the following code.

```
FB.ui({
        client_id: '12345',
        method: 'oauth',
        scope: 'email,user_birthday',
        response_type: 'token',
        redirect_uri: "https://mydomain.com/test.php" // Change this to proper address
      });
```

When we include the redirect_uri we get the following message

> ```
> API Error Code: 100 API 
> Error Description: Invalid parameter 
> Error Message: The "redirect_uri" parameter cannot be used in conjunction 
>     with the "next" parameter, which is deprecated.
> ```

We are not using the next parameter anywhere though, so not sure why it is saying that.

When we take away the `redirect_uri` we get the following message.

> ```
> API Error Code: 191 API 
> Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application 
> Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application.
> ```

Answer (score 2):

I would use the FB.login method as opposed to this given you are operating within a tab application.

Within your FB.init:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function(){
        FB.init({
            appId: 'your_app_id', 
            status: true, 
            cookie: true,
            xfbml: true,
            oauth: true
        });
        FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow(true);
    };

FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
        if(response.status == 'connected'){
            callyourfunctiontoentercompetition();
        }else{
            FB.login(function(response){
                if(response.status == 'connected'){
                    callyourfunctiontoentercompetition();
                }else{
                   handlethecancelpermissions();
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out there was a few things wrong, In my app settings I had to select "Website" and put in my site's URL, this allowed me to add the "app domain" and save it. This cleared up the 191 Error. Having website not checked off your App Domain will not save. After that it was rather simple.

Here the code that I used.

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
   FB.init({
    appId  : 'YOUR_ID',
    status : true, // check login status
    cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml  : true, // parse XFBML
    channelURL : 'http://www.your_domain.ca/channel.html', // channel.html file
    oauth  : true // enable OAuth 2.0
  });
   // This should be fired on a user initiated action

     FB.ui({ method: 'oauth', perms: 'email' }, function() { callback() });
  };
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
   }(document));

  function callback() { 

  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.authResponse) {
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      //Get user information from here
    });
  }  
    });
  }


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure the request that u r making is coming from the same domain as the one you have registered in facebook api

Answer (score 0):

In a tab you don't need to pass any parameter other than method and perms(or scope when Facebook changes it)

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
        if(response.status == 'connected'){
alert("User connected");
        }else{
FB.ui({
        method: 'oauth',
        perms: 'email,user_birthday' //change perms to scope when Facebook supports it
      }, function(response){
if(response.session){
alert("User connected");
}else if(response.installed != '1'){
alert("User canceled");
}
});
}
}
)
```